# Flutter splash screen, a white circle for andorid, is there a way to change that to black or any other color?

Tags: android, flutter

[Android Screen, As you can see that white circle behind up-help, is there a way to change the color of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK2Ql.png)

[Iphone Screen, it is working great for the iphone side, kinda what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3kEe.png)

Tried messing with the background image as well as the image size but any help would be great. Want to get rid of that white circle in the android screen.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain a package [`flutter_native_splash`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) that allows you to easily modify the Android 12 icon background color, among many other parameters.  In that package, you would change the following parameter:

```yaml
flutter_native_splash:
  android_12:
    # App icon background color.
    icon_background_color: "#111111"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `launch_background.xml` on `android/app/src/main/res/drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" /> <!-- HERE-->

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <!-- <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item> -->
</layer-list>
```